# Angular 6 Error "NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, frontend

I'm currently working on a project where I need the user to fill out an angular form and then send it to a route in my backend to process the data. The backend is in ASP.NET and I already have a functional form in HTML that's working :

```
<body>
<h2 style="text-align:center">Push notification test</h2>
<form style="align-content:center" action="SendPushNotification" method="post">
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend> Informations </legend>
            <label> Notification name : </label>
            <input name="notificationName" id="notificationName" type="text" value="Bonjour" />
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset>
            <label> Server Key : </label>
            <input name="serverKey" id="serverKey" type="text" value="AAAAuTv1XVQ:APA91bHsgOmK-quki_rRehRhON9c_y9INocubgru6_jPePiE_Zt5iVXfJ-XD43RubfIY5WEoIpFEyziByfeNRsoIlpeNi693bGZYfjjb7ULDx23sRzHQcYLCgl7y3vn-K9X8hrmQhw1oY6lSTml2aqzoi8GGBIeZYA" />
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset>
            <label> To mobile user : </label>
            <select name="selectMobile" id="selectMobile" style="width:400px" name="mobileUser">
                <option>Select Mobile User</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset>
            <label> To topic : </label>
            <input name="topicName" id="topicName" type="text" value="news" />
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset>
            <label> Message : </label>
            <textarea name="notificationMessage" id="notificationMessage" cols="40" rows="5">Comment tu vas toi ?</textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Send Notification" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**HTML Rendering**

[image]

So I'm trying to do the same thing in Angular 6 with this result but when I want to assign the route "SendNotification" to my "Submit" button I get the following error :

**Angular Rendering + Error**

[image]

**notification-form.component.html**

```
<button [routerLink]="['SendNotification']" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!notificationForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
```

The error occurs as soon as I add `[routerLink]` or add a private constructor :

```
 constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

to my `notification-form.component.ts`.
I have already tried several solutions like adding `HttpClientModule` to my `app.module.ts` but nothing works.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your time!

UPDATE:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NotificationFormComponent } from './notification-form/notification-form.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule
  ],  
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotificationFormComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: have you included router module in app.module.ts?

Comment: Yes i have I'll update the pose with my app.module.ts

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First import `RouteModule` in `app.module.ts`

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

And use it like below: (You only import `RouterModule` but need to add `forRoot([])` also.)

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
    // other imports here
  ]
```

If you have any routes use them like below. This sample code from [Angular DOC](https://angular.io/guide/router)

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in your main Component (`app.component.html`) add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hi ! Thx for your time, i tried your solution but now I'm getting this error :  zone.js:665 Unhandled Promise rejection: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base element to the document.

Comment: did you add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to app.component.html ?

Comment: and also check you index.html has `<base href="/">` in `head` tag

Comment: Yeah I Added one and my index.html has one :/

Comment: Yeah I Added it to my _Layout.cshtml ! Thank you !

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: Hey you saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

If you are using

**`RouterModule.forChild(routes)`**

try it to replace with

**`RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`**

Comment: thanks! It worked for me :)

Answer (score 9):

For those also struggling, with the cryptic/unhelpful error messages from the Angular compiler, make sure you have this somewhere:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([])
```

I was only using `RouterModule.forChild([])`, adding a forRoot() in one of the modules fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is using npm link(s), the following does the job:

In `.angular-cli.json` add/replace:

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {},
    "build": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding as this is the top answer when googling `NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!`

If you are running into this on your unit tests and you are not testing the `Router` itself. Try importing the `RouterTestingModule`

`import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';`

Comment: Also, add it to your TestBed imports

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I only put:

```
<base href="/">
```

In my `head` tag in the `index.html` file.

```
...
<head>
  ...
  <title>Name of page</title>
  <base href="/">
</head>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please check this link**
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterStateSnapshot

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterState, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router'; 

@Component({
  templateUrl:'template.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(router: Router) {
   const state: RouterState = router.routerState;
   const snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot = state.snapshot;
   console.log(state);
   console.log(snapshot);
   //...
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

The tag `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is the place where your app is going to render the different routes. For example, in the app.component.html you can have:

```
<header>
    <bt-toolbar></bt-toolbar>
</header>

<main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

With this template I have a top bar always visible and below is the content of the diferent routes.

Add to your app.module.ts this in the imports array:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'SendNotification', component: YourComponent }
```

Comment: Hi ! Where should I add it ?