# StaticInjectorError Router in Angular

Tags: angular

Hey guys I just updated the some code, please see if you can help me now

This is app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
export const routes: Routes = [
 {
    canActivate: [AuthguardService],
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'myprofile/socialprofiles',
    // redirectTo: 'dashboard', 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    //canActivate: [LoginGuard]
  },
  { path: '**', component: P404Component } 
];

@NgModule({
imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This is the error I am getting - 
While StaticInjectorError Router in Angular, getting the following error

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AppComponent -> Router]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppComponent -> Router]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!
        at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
        at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
        at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
        at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
        at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
        at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
        at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
        at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
        at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21907)
        at resolveDep (core.js:22278)
```

Comment: Did you import the RouterModule in your application ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 Error "NullInjectorError: No provider for Router!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419602/angular-6-error-nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-router)

Comment: Yes i do import the RouterModule @MichaelDesigaud

Comment: Can you copy/pase some code ?

Comment: I added routing.ts file, what else you want? @MichaelDesigaud

Comment: Where is the declaration of the AppComponent ?